# Sort array of n integers in range [1, n^α], when α is a positive integer

Tags: arrays, sorting

I am trying to think about an algorithm which sorts array of n integers in range [image: range] in time complexity [image: O(n)], where [image: alpha] is a positive integer.

I can't use Counting sort, since the time complexity will be [image].

How can I use the information about the range of the numbers, and sort the array, when iterating over the range is impossible?